# How to set coder for Pcollection within PcollectionTuple when the schema data I want to use is part of pcollection itself

Tags: java, serialization, apache-beam

I am trying to process data  events (streaming data from pubsub) with dynamic schema. The schema can change and I am maintaining schema in a schema registry keyed by schema id.

I shall be passing the schema registry as sideinput to the pardo tranform that shall process my data and create pcollection of an event type and add it to tuple.

The event data I process shall have a schemaid which can be used to key into schema registry and serialize data (jsontoRow). I also keep schema-id used with the data.

```
PCollectionTuple output = input.apply("FromJson", ParDo.of(
                    new DoFn<String, EventWrapper<String, RowWrapper>>() {

                        @ProcessElement
                        public void processElement(ProcessContext context, @Element String inputRecord,
                                                   MultiOutputReceiver out) {
                      
                                Map<String, Map<String, Schema>> schemaMap = context.sideInput(schemaMapView);
                                
                                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(inputRecord);
                                    String schemaIdStr =
                                            obj.getJSONObject(Schema).getString("schemaid");


                                    Schema inputSchema = schemaMap.get(schemaIdStr);
                                    Row row = jsonToRow(newObjectMapperWith(
                                            RowJsonDeserializer.forSchema(inputSchema)),
                                            obj.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("payload").toString());

                                    String eventName = obj.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("payload").getJSONObject("event").toString();

                                    TupleTag<EventWrapper<String, RowWrapper>> tupleTagInUse = TupleTagGenerator.getTupleTag(eventName);
                                    if (tupleTagInUse == null) {
                                        tupleTagInUse = validEvents;
                                    }
                                    RowWrapper rowData = new RowWrapper(row,schemaIdStr);
                                    out.get(tupleTagInUse).output(new EventWrapper<>(inputRecord, rowData));
                          
                            } 
                        }
                    }).withSideInputs(schemaMapView)
                    .withOutputTags(validEvents, TupleTagList.of(invalidEvents)
                                    .and(new ArrayList<TupleTag<?>>(tupleTagList))));
```

I now need to setCoder for each pCollection created from above pardo. I don't have access to schema map outside context. But I do have schema-id stored within rowWrapper and also Beam row should be maintaining the schema it uses to serialize the data.

Q1: can I run some transformation on pcollectionTuple to process each pcollection to extract schema from row data stored within pcollection and do setcoder on pcollection object?

Q2: can I create a side output in my parDO, a key value pair or hash map to maintain schema-id to schema mapping that I could use external to pardo?

Q3: can I set the coder for the Pcollection created within pardo where I have schema object available?

Answer (score 0):

Coders (and their associated schemas) must be set as part of pipeline construction, and cannot rely on the data itself (which is only present after the pipeline has been completely defined, optimized, and sent for execution).

If you need to have dynamic data like this, you'll need to use some kind of a container type whose Coder can handle dynamic fields. (As you're already using JSON, you could consider just continuing to do so for your dynamically schema'd data.)

Comment: Thanks for your input Robert, but can you elaborate more on your container type solution. I am bit new to apache beam.

I have tried to create a custome collection RowWrapper which shall store beam row and schema-id, possibly can store schema as well but I am not sure how to specify coder for the collection

Comment: You need a Coder that can handle arbitrary schemas, e.g. you could have a coder that encodes elements as (Schema, ElementEncodedWithSchema). Schema-ids can't be used as there's no way to share newly created schemas between workers.